Why 8bit quantized fine tuning of a model occupy more memory than just original model fine tuning?
I trying to fine tune Mistral model for 5 epochs. It shows it take 72 hours with 8 bit quantized fine tuning but 48 hours with just original mode fine tuning. Also memory footprint is higher for 8bit quantized fine tuning. Below is the code where I am loading model for 8 bit quantization.
bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
        load_in_8bit = True , 
        llm_int8_enable_fp32_cpu_offload = True, 
        llm_int8_has_fp16_weight = False,
    )

    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
            base_model,
            quantization_config=bnb_config,
            torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
            device_map="auto",
            trust_remote_code=True,
    )

Someone please explain why it is happening. Am I making any mistake?

My guess is that the original model in 16bit format is a better and more compact representation of the LLM. It is going through contortions to fit it all into 8 bit coding.

Then what is the motive of using quantization in model while fine tuning?. For what model it actual benefit us?

The slower training is expected. Quantization adds more operations in exchange for lower memory footprint. Higher memory footprint is unexpected. Are you sure training with quantization is supported? Typically you quantize the model and train a LORA adapter in fp16/fp32. Finetuning the base model in fp8 is unusual

If you can quantise it down to a more compact 8bit representation and it still works OK then that is a good thing but you have to be careful that you don't push it too far and lose important information at the same time or have it expand to compensate for the quantisation in the way that you have seen.

I tried quantized lora fine tuning. Still the similar situation.
